# Change background dependent upon arriving URL

Tags: html, css, background

Hi and hope someone can help.

I have a live site and also a development site where I test out new code before deployment but basically they have the same content e.g.

- Live = www.myserver.com/live/index.html
- Development = www.myserver.com/development/index.html

Is there a way of setting the (say) CSS background property dependent upon the url that has been used to arrive at the site.

My current CSS =

```
body {
    background: #eff;
    /* change this to background: #ccc; if on development site */
    margin:25px;
}
```

Why?
Well, I frequently find myself uploading or testing new code on the wrong site.

Not a big issue I know but useful if I could have a visual clue as to which site I'm testing.

My thanks for your interest.

**Now Solved** Thanks for input from @Adam Buchanan Smith, @Dekel and Mr Green.
I sort of used @Dekel's logic but changed it to jQuery along the following lines:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// Set background dependent upon url i.e. www.myserver.com/cab or www.myserver.com/cab2
// cab2 is the development site, cab the live site
// Also change text in div id="live" from 'Live Site' to 'Development Site' if arrives at by cab2   
    if (document.location.pathname.indexOf('cab2') > -1){
    $('body').css({"background":"#BFFFDF"});
    document.getElementById('live').innerHTML = "Development Site";
    } else {
        $('body').css({"background":"#efffff"});
        document.getElementById('live').innerHTML = "Live Site";
    }
}
</script>
```

My thanks to all for your interest!

Comment: You will need javascript or a server side language, what do you prefer?

Comment: I have both. I'm using javascript on both and PHP for a contact form I have on the site, thanks Adam.

Comment: I heard it is possible to load css through `.htaccess` file. Load a small css file which holds your development state which determines styles through htaccess by checking the url. I don't suggest coding in html, js or css files though.

Comment: Done that, thanks @Dekel, appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not something you can do in pure html/css, but you can use both javascript and server side language for that.

In javascript you can check if the `document.location.hostname` or `document.location.pathname` to check the domain/url you are currently using.

In javascript for example you can use:

```
if (document.location.pathname.indexOf('development') > -1) {
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    body.setAttribute('class', body.getAttribute('class') + ' development')
}
```

Using PHP you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'development')) {
    echo "<body class=\"development\">";
} else {
    echo "<body>";
}
```

And in the `css` file you can use:

```
body {
    background: #eff;
}
body.development {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Only mention of `.development` will be enough.

Comment: Thanks @Dekel that'll get me going! Thanks too Mr Green that will get me Googling .htaccess and what I can do with that. Appreciate all your input.

Comment: @RogerW, you are welcome. I updated the answer also with a javascript example. You are welcome to approve/voteup the answer if it was helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: @RogerW welcome. I suggested to code in .htaccess file because the code is only related to development site. You can just ignore the htaccess file changes while deploying to live server.

Comment: Yep, thanks both. I'll be experimenting with the javascript provided by @Dekel over the next 24 hours and upload my solution in due course.
Isn't StackOverflow great?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically something like this could work for you in just plain javascript using `document.referrer;`

```
<body onload="checkURL()">
</body>
<script>
function checkURL(){
var testPage = "www.testpage.com";
var livePage = "www.livepage.com";
var lastPage = document.referrer;

if (lastPage == livePage){
//do something here
}
else if {lastPage == testPage}
//do something else
}
else{
//umm what did you do?
}
</script>
```